# Sequelize cli error this.lib.database is not a constructor

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Getting this error using sequelize cli for migrations it was working previously but dont know why it isnt now and there is no details to this error

sequelize db:migrate:undo:all

Sequelize CLI [Node: 18.12.1, CLI: 6.6.0, ORM: 6.21.0]

Loaded configuration file "config\config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: this.lib.Database is not a constructor

i tried removing sequelize in node modules folder and re-installing

Comment: re you sure you didn't find `lib.Database` in the whole project?

Comment: No, i used the sequelize cli init to generate my sequelize files thus, models,migrations,config and seeders